# Insertar un nodo en una lista dada la posición y el elemento

Tags: c++

Para ello tengo estos dos struct

```
struct ListNode{ 
     Element key; 
     ListNodePtr next; 
};

struct List{
    ListNodePtr head;
};
```

y esta función

```
ListNodePtr listNodeCreate (Element e);
```

Concretamente, la función que tengo que crear sería esta:

```
bool listInsert(ListPrt l, Element x, Position i)
```

Comment: Ya, ... ¿Cuál es el problema? Te invito a leer: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Pues que no se como hacer el codigo de la funcion que tengo que crear

Comment: Stackoverflow es una comunidad que resuelve dudas especificas. Aquí no hacemos códigos. Así que te recomiendo agregar el código que tengas hecho y a partir de ese código, elaboras tu duda en detalle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que crear una lista conectada donde next se refiere al puntero que indica la dirección del siguiente nodo.

El programa sería algo asi:

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode
{
    int data;
    ListNode* next = nullptr;
};

struct List
{
    ListNode* head = nullptr;
};

List list; //Esta sería la lista y es una variable global para acceder al puntero que inicia la lista
ListNode* tempNode = nullptr; // nodo temporal para almacenar otros nodos y se utiliza para conectarlos

ListNode* listNodeCreate(int e);
bool listInsert(ListNode* listNode, int data, unsigned int position);

int main()
{
    tempNode = new ListNode;
    list.head = listNodeCreate(0); //creo el primer nodo y se lo asigno a la cabeza de la lista
    tempNode = list.head; //Actualizo el nodo temporal para utilizarlo en las proximas insercciones a la lista

    listNodeCreate(1); //creo mas nodos
    listNodeCreate(2);
    listNodeCreate(3);

    ListNode* node = nullptr; //creo un nodo nulo para testear la funcion de instertar
    listInsert(node, 22, 2);

    ListNode* tmp; //creo otro nodo temporal para recorrer la lista e imprimirla
    tmp = list.head;
    while (tmp != nullptr) //si tmp es nulo significa que llegue al final de la lista y salgo del bucle
    {
        std::cout << tmp->data << "->";
        tmp = tmp->next; // actualizo el nodo temporal para que apunte al siguiente nodo
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Presiona Enter para Finalizar" << std::endl;
    getchar(); //espera que ingreser un caracter para que puedas ver el resultado en consola

    return 0;
}

ListNode* listNodeCreate(int e)
{
    ListNode* listNode = new ListNode; //creo un nuevo nodo
    listNode->data = e; //le asigno un dato en este caso int

    tempNode->next = listNode; //el temp node primero apunta a la cabeza entonces actualizo el next de la cabeza para que apunte al nuevo nodo
    tempNode = tempNode->next; //Actualizo el nodo temporal para que apunte al ultimo nodo creado y utilizarlo en las proximas insercciones a la lista

    return listNode;
}

bool listInsert(ListNode * listNode, int data, unsigned int position)
{
    ListNode* tmp; //creo un nodo temporal
    tmp = list.head; //y lo apunto a la cabeza

    if (position == 0) //aqui se podria hacer una rutina para reemplazar la cabeza o simplemente return false ya que es una posición invalida para insertar un nuevo nodo
    {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < position -1; i++) //recorro los nodos hasta la posición anterior a la insercción por eso uso position -1
    {
        if (!tmp->next) //si el nodo es nulo significa que esta tratando de insertar en una posición mas alta que la cantidad de nodos en la lista
            return false;

        tmp = tmp->next; //actualizao el nodo temporal
    }

    if (!tmp) //valido que no sea nulo el nodo temporal
        return false;

    listNode = new ListNode; //creo el nuevo nodo a insertar
    listNode->data = data; //le asigno los datos
    listNode->next = tmp->next; //actualizo el nodo al que apunta next
    tmp->next = listNode; //actualizo el nodo anterior para que apunte al nuevo nodo

    return true;
}
```

Aclaración: Al final del programa se debe usar delete por cada new que se usó para crear los nodos. Si no el programa deja "memory leaks".

Comment: No se por que no gustó mi respuesta, es un poco de ayuda al menos. Pero dame 5 mins. esto es fácil.

Comment: Lo siento, no fui yo. Yo considero esta respuesta útil. Muchas gracias

Comment: Te dieron voto negativo porque le hiciste el trabajo al OP. Si te das cuenta esta pregunta no está bien formulada (por cierto, yo no te di -2).

Comment: Te invito a como [responder en stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: El voto negativo fue previo al codigo